# invalid literal for int() with base 10 (Python) and how would I get this to work like a text based game?

Tags: python, int

I'm trying to create a text based game as my first project (somewhat similar to Candy Box but on a much smaller scale) for which you first of all must buy drugs and then sell them to make a profit, once I have the basics working I then hope to include more advanced systems such as upgrades, however I am currently running into errors

Here is my code :

```
    import random

commands = ["buy","sell","info","money","weed"]
player_money = 200
weed = 0

def roll():
    score= random.randint(1,100)

def win_lose():
    score_needed=amount_to_sell+20
    if(score>score_needed):
        print("The deal was successful, you made $",10*amount_to_sell)
        player_money+=10*amount_to_sell
    else:
        print("The deal got busted!")

def sell_bud():
    amount_to_sell = input (int("How much are you selling (grams)?"))
    if(amount_to_sell<weed):
        weed-= weed-amount_to_sell
        roll()
        win_lose()

def buy_bud():
    amount_to_buy =input (int("How much are you buying (grams)?" "\n" "The current price is $7.50/g"))
    if (float(amount_to_buy*7.50<player_money)):
        weed+=amount_to_buy
        print("You now have", weed,"g")
    else:
        print("You can afford that much")


def info():
  print('\n'.join(commands))
```

and he is the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 301, in runcode
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "", line 36, in buy_bud
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'How much are you buying (grams)?\nThe current price is $7.50/g'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `int` and `input` the wrong way around.

```
input(int("..."))
```

tries to create an integer of the message,

```
int(input("..."))
```

tries to create an integer of the user's input.

More generally, here are a few suggestions:

1. Create a `Player` class, with a `drugs` dictionary (e.g. `{"weed": 10}`) and `money` and `score` float attributes. This will hold everything together, and gives you the possibility of multiple players later.
2. Make `buy` and `sell` instance methods of the `Player` class, with the `drug` and `price` given as arguments so they can be more general.
3. From a gameplay point of view, trying to beat a random number isn't a great mechanic. At least tell the player the price before they decide to sell! You may need to think of a way to keep track of price paid for each tranche of drugs, so that you can work out profit for each sale.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, never would've noticed that myself, I'm still learning so there's a lot of silly mistakes.

Comment: No problem, I've added a few more general suggestions

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but would you be able to give me a bit of information on classes? I haven't reached that far yet. I agree on point 3 but I couldn't think of a better way of doing it, I'll try and change it once everything is running fully.